# WPF Loading datagrid with needed information only

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid which shows the loaded data. Now my problem is that , i don't want to display all the information into the DataGrid. e.i UserID,Password and Gander. i only know it using Gridview where i can add the columns i want manually not by codding. Please help me.

```
  //method that save to d grid
    public static List<ObjectUser> GetListAllUsers()
    {
        List<ObjectUser> oUserList = new List<ObjectUser>();

        try
        {
            SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand oCOmmand = new SqlCommand();
            oCOmmand.Connection = oConnection;
            DataSet oDs = new DataSet();
            oCOmmand.CommandText = @"select u.* , c.Company 
                                    from UserEnrollment u
                                    inner join [dbo].[Company] c on u.CompanyID = c.CompanyID";
            SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(oCOmmand.CommandText,   oCOmmand.Connection);
            Adapter.Fill(oDs);

            if (oDs.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in oDs.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    ObjectUser oGet = new ObjectUser();
                   oGet.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["UserID"].ToString());
                   oGet.UserName = dr["UserName"].ToString();
                   oGet.Password = dr["Password"].ToString();
                    oGet.FullNames = dr["FullNames"].ToString();
                    oGet.Surname = dr["Surname"].ToString();
                    oGet.Email = dr["EmailAddress"].ToString();
                   oGet.GenderID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["GenderID"].ToString());
                    oGet.CompanyName = dr["Company"].ToString();

                    oUserList.Add(oGet);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create one property which holds Hiding columns for your datagrid like this.

   string[] arr= new string[2] {"Column1", "Column2"};
2. Now use above arr in your autogenerating column event as shown in code

You can use AutogeneratingColumns Event of datagrid to achieve above functionality.

You can use any one of below code as per your requirement

Case 1: If you have list of columns which you do not want to show then you can use below code in your autogenerating column event of datagrid

```
    if(e != null)
    {
        if(arr.Contains(e.Column.Header))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
           //Here if you want to just hide the column and wants to generate the column
           // e.Column.Visibility= Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

Case 2: If you have list of columns which you want to show then you can use below code in your autogenerating column event of datagrid

```
    string[] VisibleColumns = //Here populate string array with list of columns you want to show
    if (e != null)
    {
        if (!VisibleColumns.Contains(e.Column.Header))
        {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Ashok, must i put the arrarys inside USerGrid button or must it be separate, this is what i did so far

Comment: it will be separate. You can store it in your code behind variable or properties and can initialize it before grid binding logic. if this answer really helps you then please mark it as answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. i am i bit lost as am still new. i manage to hide them using indexs like , UserGrid.Columns[2].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;  the only problem am having is it only hides when i click the grid. i changed the code an put it on form load and it throes errors saying ; Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: in your autogenerating column you dont need to do anything. if you want to generate column and dont want to show only then you can set visibility. my logic will not create the column at all so it wont get any problem for you.

Comment: Your sequence of line should be like this . 1)datagrid.Autogeneratingcolumn += your event 2) datagrid.Itemsource=//some data

Comment: Now how do i make the first index of datagrid get selected, like i will delete ID 7 and after that the selected index must be one

Comment: when do you want to get selected ? you can simply do datagrid.SelectedIndex=0; please mark it as answer, if it really helps you.thanks.

Comment: when the form loads, the forst row of datagrid must be selected and even if i can click row 5 to delete, it must go back and select the first index. i tried that one and it is not working

Comment: after grid binding logic put above line datagrid.selectedIndex=0;

Comment: also set DataGridSelectionUnit Property to row

Comment: do you want to delete first row or fifth one ?

Comment: i would suggest for delete issue post a new question. and if for hiding information above solution worked then please mark it as answer so others can also go with above solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply hide the columns you don't want to display after setting the datasource of the datagridview:

```
myDataGridView.Columns["UserID"].Visible = false;
myDataGridView.Columns["Password"].Visible = false;
myDataGridView.Columns["GenderID"].Visible = false;
```